# How to perform Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE) with LSTM as estimator in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lstm, rfe

I am trying to identify the important features in a data frame containing stock data. I plan on using LSTM to predict closing prices later on. I currently have the following:

```
df_stockData = pdr.DataReader(ticker, data_source='yahoo', start='2012-10-20',
                              end=str(date.today() - timedelta(days=1)))

def performRFE():
    rfecv = RFECV(
        estimator=RandomForestRegressor(), #I want to use a LSTM instead
        min_features_to_select=1,
        step=2,
        n_jobs=-1,
        scoring="r2",
        cv=5,
    )
    cols_rfe = list(df_stockData.columns)
    cols_rfe.remove('Close')
    rfecv.fit(StandardScaler().fit_transform(df_stockData.loc[:, cols_rfe]),
              np.array(df_stockData['Close'].values).reshape(-1, ))
    return list(df_stockData.loc[:, cols_rfe].columns[rfecv.support_])

selected_features = performRFE()
print("Selected Features: {}".format(selected_features))
```

As you can see above, I get the data from yahoo finance and I try to find important features which can help me predict the close price. Here I use `RandomForestRegressor()` as estimator. Instead of this I want to use LSTM because later on I use LSTM to predict the close price. Could anyone help me with this? I have been unable to figure it out yet.